# Does not work in the production assembly remoteEntry.mjs from nx (Module Federation)

Tags: angular, typescript, monorepo, angular-module-federation

With local development, MF works, however, with a production build of remoteEntry.js from the host to the remote port returns the
`Failed to fetch dynamically imported module error: http://localhost:2000/remoteEntry.mjs.`

Although it is true. The error is most likely due to the fact that the browser does not process it as a script. And I looked at the sources, the js option is not described anywhere. What can be done?

tsconfig example:

```
"target": "esnext",
"module": "esnext",
"lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
```

Env: Angular 13, NX Monorepo, @nrwl/angular/module-federation(libs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. The problem turned out to be in the nginx configuration. We need to add nginx to mime.types

```
server
{
   include mime.types;
   types
   {
      application/javascript mjs;
   }

...

}
```

Comment: would you please expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

1- Add the following deployment tag to the "project.json" in your host app.

```
"deploy": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "outputs": [],
  "options": {
    "command": "rm -rf production && mkdir production && cp -r dist/apps/<YOUR-HOST-APP>/* production && cp -r dist/apps/{<REMOTE-APP1,REMOTE-APP2>} production && http-server -p 3000 -a localhost production"
  }
}
```

2- Add implicit dependencies to the "project.json" in your host app.

```
"implicitDependencies": ["<REMOTE-APP1>", "<REMOTE-APP2>"]
```

3- Inside your "module-federation.config.js" file, in your remote app add your remotes: ['', 'REMOTE-URL'], i.e.

```
const { withModuleFederation } = require('@nrwl/angular/module- 
federation');
const config = require('./module-federation.config');
module.exports = withModuleFederation({
...config,
remotes: [
['<REMOTE-APP1>', 'http://localhost:3000/<REMOTE-APP1>'],
['<REMOTE-APP2>', 'http://localhost:3000/<REMOTE-APP2>']
]   
});
```

4- Disable cache from Chrome Developer Tools.

[image]

5- Build and Deploy.

```
nx build <HOST-APP>
nx deploy <HOST-APP>
```

6- Enjoy loading the "production/REMOTE-APP/remoteEntry.mjs" files from the host application after building the mfe workspace with NX.